# Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi everybody I have a code that give me this error

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\application\controllers\admin\home.php on line 3

I have no idea why it's showing this error…

The code of C:\wamp\www\project\application\controllers\admin\home.php is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {

function index()
{
    redirect('admin/login');
}

function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    //session_destroy();
    redirect('admin/login');
}
}
?>
```

The code of C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries\MY_Controller.php is

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
}

}
```

And also if I place

> class Home extends CI_Controller

instead of

> class Home extends MY_Controller

in the

> C:\wamp\www\project\application\controller\admin\home.php

file and try to load the

> C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries\MY_Controller.php

in the constructor of

> C:\wamp\www\project\application\controllers\admin\home.php

it shows

> Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object

Why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put class files to `core` instead of `library` folder when you extending System classes. Put `MY_Controller.php` in `core` folder.

Comment: Thanks.. It's working now.. But I have seen many examples where they are placing the file in libraries. For me why it's not working. Any idea..

Comment: If you extend system classes you put the files inside core not library

Comment: @Broncha Thanks for the help. One more thing I want know. If I place "class Home extends CI_Controller" instead of "class Home extends MY_Controller"in the "C:\wamp\www\project\application\contorller\admin\home.php" file and try to load the "C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries\MY_Controller.php" in the constructor of "C:\wamp\www\project\application\contorller\admin\home.php", it shows "Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object". Any idea why it's showing this error?

Comment: Many examples rely on an older version of CI where it was correct to place it in the library folder. If I'm not mistaking this has been changed to the core folder since 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Core controllers need to be stored in `application/core/`

So when you extend an object, it will look for it there.  Library folder is used for storage of 'external' libraries, which you must explicitly include in your controller:

Ex:
`$this->load->library('class name');`

Info on libraries here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html

Comment: But if I place "class Home extends CI_Controller" instead of "class Home extends MY_Controller" in the "C:\wamp\www\project\application\contorller\admin\home.php" file and try to load the "C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries\MY_Controller.php" in the constructor of "C:\wamp\www\project\application\contorller\admin\home.php", it shows "Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object".

Comment: @Subhra, please update your error in your main question, ALSO your controller path is wrong `contorller`?